# Abstract val with annotation in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

Can I write:

```
@IdRes
abstract fun getHeaderId(): Int
```

With a `val` instead of a `fun` in kotlin? It complains I need a backing field or delegate when i write:

```
@IdRes <-- errors
abstract val headerId: Int
```

Which is the most idiomatic in this case? One-liner with a `fun` or mess around with a backing field (I'm not used to backing fields, maybe it's change-resistance, i have never really used them so i think they are unpleasant)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since abstract `val` or `var` is just a function without a backing field it cannot be annotated by `IdRes` annotation but there is a workaround. You can use it like this:

```
@get:IdRes
abstract val headerId: Int
```

EDIT:

Why does this works? We need to closer inspect `IdRes` annotation and its source code:

```
@Documented
@Retention(CLASS)
@Target({METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD, LOCAL_VARIABLE})
public @interface IdRes {
}
```

As we can see this annotation can be used on methods, parameters, fields and local variables. When we use `abstract val` it's neither of those since it is abstract and we cannot have abstract fields in Java. Normally equivalent of `abstract val something: Int` in Java is:

```
private int something

public int getSomething() {
    return something;
}
```

From example, it's easy to see that the private field is what is called backing field of a property and you can't have those as abstract so that was the problem.

Comment: But in this case, someone using the abstract class may get around the annotation by just writing override `val headerId: Int = 5` in his implementation of the abstract class

Comment: i just ran into this post with basically the same problem (except my val is in an interface) and came to the same solution, but it doesnt really work. in classes that implement my interface and override this val, the annotation is not taken into account and i can pass any int

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in @AtulGupta comment, @theKarlo 's answer does not force the subclass to pass in an `IdRes`.

Therefore, an alternative to

```
@IdRes
abstract fun getHeaderId(): Int
```

and

```
@get:IdRes
abstract val headerId: Int
```

Is to pass the value into the constructor of the class itself, so that the backing field issue can be avoided and the subclass is forced to pass in an `IdRes`.

For example:

```
abstract class SomeClass(@IdRes val idRes: Int)
```